Craft e-commerce shipping issues with set-up
I manage a charity website built on Craft 3.9.13, which is currently being upgraded to 4.0. Unfortunately, there are no handover notes regarding this, so I am working on establishing best practices to manage the existing postage setup.
Recently, a colleague accidentally altered some of the rules, which has significantly impacted the postage amounts for all products. My question is whether it’s possible to have two postage methods running simultaneously.
What I’ve done is apply a postage rule so that if someone buys an item within a specific category (same type of product) and purchases multiple quantities, the postage adjusts accordingly by reducing the amount compared to buying the items individually. This rule is applied across all methods. However, at the moment, it's preventing products with different methods from being purchased together. The system just shows that no shipping options are available.
I’m guessing it would be best to base the postage on weight and postage type, but our products don't have that information available. Our flexion product is very limited so we just want a quick solution that is easy to maintain. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I’m still quite new to this system.
Thank you
